# HKHealthStore requestAuthorizationToShareTypes:readTypes:completion always returns success?

Tags: ios, ios8, healthkit

I can't seem to capture and handle the user cancelling HealthKit premissions.  The completion block always returns success and nil Error.

```
[[DataManager healthStore] requestAuthorizationToShareTypes:dataTypesToWrite
                                                  readTypes:dataTypesToRead
                                                 completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error)
 {
     if (!success)
     {
         NSLog(@"You didn't allow HealthKit to access these read/write data types. In your app, try to handle this error gracefully when a user decides not to provide access. The error was: %@. If you're using a simulator, try it on a device.", error);
     }

     if (completion)
     {
         completion(success,error);
     }
 }];
```

Comment: I'm seeing this as well.  Guessing its still a leftover iOS8 bug =/

Comment: I've experienced this bug as well, here's the open radar link: http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5811667216629760

Answer (score 4):

The success parameter does not indicate whether your app was granted the authorizations that were requested.  It only indicates whether the user was successfully prompted for authorization (if prompting was necessary).  The success parameter will be NO and the error will be non-nil if the user cancels the prompt or the prompt could not be shown for some reason.

Also note that, by design, there is no way to query whether the application has read access for a type.  You may only query whether the application is authorized to save objects of a type, using the **-[HKHealthStore authorizationStatusForType:]** API.

Answer (score 2):

This was indeed a bug. It was fixed in iOS 8 Golden Master seed.

Comment: iOS 9.3.1 - the same issue

Answer (score -1):

If you want to know whether any of the permissions are given for healthkit, you can use this method.

```
-(BOOL) anyPermissionIsGiven {

NSMutableArray * authArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

[authArray addObject:[HKQuantityType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietarySodium]];
[authArray addObject:[HKQuantityType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryCarbohydrates]];
[authArray addObject:[HKQuantityType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryFiber]];
[authArray addObject:[HKQuantityType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryEnergyConsumed]];
[authArray addObject:[HKQuantityType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryProtein]];
[authArray addObject:[HKQuantityType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryVitaminA]];
[authArray addObject:[HKQuantityType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryVitaminB6]];
[authArray addObject:[HKQuantityType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryVitaminC]];
[authArray addObject:[HKQuantityType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryVitaminE]];
[authArray addObject:[HKQuantityType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryVitaminK]];
[authArray addObject:[HKQuantityType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryCalcium]];
[authArray addObject:[HKQuantityType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryThiamin]];
[authArray addObject:[HKQuantityType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryFolate]];
[authArray addObject:[HKQuantityType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryPhosphorus]];
[authArray addObject:[HKQuantityType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryMagnesium]];
[authArray addObject:[HKQuantityType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryPotassium]];

BOOL anyPermissionGiven = NO;
for (HKQuantityType * quantityType in authArray) {
    if([self.healthStore authorizationStatusForType:quantityType] == HKAuthorizationStatusSharingAuthorized) {
        anyPermissionGiven = YES;
        break;
    }
}

return anyPermissionGiven;
```

}